# Bootstrap and tables (shift cells)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap. 
I see a lot of examples of bootstrap samples, also with tables, and I saw that resizing my window browser, the table become lesser. Now, I would like to know if there is any way to shift cells from a row to another. 
I try to explain better my question:

if I have the browser opened in a large window I see my table with one row and 5 columns, like this:

```
X X X X X
```

now, I resize the browser and I want to see the table like this

```
X X X
X X
```

lesser...

```
X X
X X
X
```

lesser...

```
X
X
X
X
X
```

Is this possible or I'm just dreaming?

I asked for bootstrap but if there is any other solution it's accepted!

Comment: Just with CSS you can use `float` or `inline-block`

Comment: @Danko: display: float or diaplay: inline-block like css attrinutes of a td?

Comment: If you float the table cells, some of the table's layout might break, but you can restore that. See http://jsfiddle.net/6v68u/

Comment: @simbabque: this seems quite good for what I'm looking for... (http://jsfiddle.net/6v68u/2/) the problem is only that cells in a specific row, If go in a new line, doesn't add the separation row on top...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my advice is to use divs and they will render as you want. 
here you can understand very easy how you can use the grid, so you can have the result that you need http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed